# Xcode Swift NavigationLink hitbox problem

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, navigationview

//The hit box of NavigationLink remains the same even after using padding or offset. How could someone move it along with its image

//

NavigationView {
NavigationLink  {NextPage()

```
                }
                label: {
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                            .offset(y:200)
                            .ignoresSafeArea()
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                        .border(Color.red)
                    }
```

Comment: Please include code, not images of code, which can't be copied/pasted, searched, or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a .background. Something like

```
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                            .offset(y:200)
                            .ignoresSafeArea()
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                        .border(Color.red)
                        .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
```

should be sufficient.